# How to add repository by ansible playbook

Tags: ubuntu, ansible

I want to do below command by ansible playbook

```
add-apt-repository cloud-archive:rocky
```

after some search I find this solution

```
- name: Add repositories
  apt_repository: repo='cloud-archive:rocky' state=present
```

But it does not work.What is the correct way to do that command by ansible playbook?

Comment: You've tagged this question with both `ubuntu` and `centos`, but `centos` doesn't use `apt`. Where exactly are you running this playbook?

Comment: you are right. I want to run it on ubuntu

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean? When you run the playbook, does it fail with an error (and what is the error)? Or does it appear to work, but the repository has not actually been added to your apt configuration?

Comment: after I run playbook it show failed in red color.

Comment: Can you please post the error message?

Comment: it just show failed by red color

Comment: use -vvvv for getting more info on the error. i.e like `ansible-playbook <playbook_name> -vvvv`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ansible's [Shell module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/shell_module.html) passing the -y switch to add-apt-repository

```
- name: Ensure to add repository
  shell: sudo add-apt-repository cloud-archive:rocky -y
```

Answer (score 0):

For ubuntu this repository module can be used, this does work and you can proceed with rest of the installation

```
 - name: Add php repository
   apt_repository:
      repo: ppa:ondrej/php
      state: present
```

Ref: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/apt_repository_module.html

Shell can definately do it but when you start working on production environment having specific module for the job is advisable to avoid any security/best practices violations